# Change style for array of DIVS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have 100 DIVS in an array called '**lights**', appended to the page with a unique ID. Some of those DIVS are also in another array called '**frozen**'.

How can I change the background color of the DIVS in '**lights**' but not the divs in the '**frozen**' array?

For example, to change all of the divs I would use:

```
for(var l=0;l<LIGHTS_NUMOF;l++){

$("#light"+l).css("background-color", "#ff0000");

}
```

Generating the array:

```
var LIGHTS_NUMOF = 100;
var lights = [];

for(var l=0;l<LIGHTS_NUMOF;l++){
    var newLight = $("<div class=\"light\" id=\"light"+l+"\"></div>");
    $(".lights").append(newLight);
    lights.push(newLight);
}
```

However, this obviously changes ALL of the divs.

How do I avoid changing the DIVS which are in the '**frozen**' array?

Ideally I would like to express lights.backgroundcolor = 'red' where DIV isn't 'frozen'.

Adding DIV to 'frozen':

```
$( ".light" ).click(function() {
frozen.push(this);
});
```

Comment: add jQuery tag, you are using jQuery here.

Comment: To sum up. You got arrays of dom elements?? JQuery dom elements? or only ids?

Comment: You are not using arrays... you using a FOR and some Ids... Show us the structure os your "arrays".. I didnt understand yet...

Comment: What does you HTML look like? You might be able to do this with a few cleverly designed CSS rules.

Comment: And how do you manipule the fronzers divs?

Comment: When clicking a DIV it is added to the Frozen array. Is it easier to move the element between the two rather than filtering?

Comment: Are you adding the id number or the element? we need to know what we have to compare, if we are comparing two numbers or two objects...

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually looking at items in the DOM, you can easily do what you want using [jQuery.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) like the following example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#changeLights").on("click", function() {
    $(".lights").not(".frozen").addClass("frozen");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height : 50px;
  width : 50px;
  background-color : #CCC;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.frozen {
  background-color : #F00;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lights"></div>
<div class="lights"></div>
<div class="lights frozen"></div>
<div class="lights"></div>
<div class="lights frozen"></div>
<div class="lights frozen"></div>
<input id="changeLights" type="button" value="Change" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(var l=0;l<LIGHTS_NUMOF;l++){
    if(frozenArray.indexOf(lightsArray[l]) == -1){ // if id is not in frozen array
        $("#light"+l).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all...
Try modify this part of your code

```
$(".light").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("frozen");
});
```

Then to get all of that is not frozen, do this:

```
$(".light").not(".frozen").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
```